# how to subset on both values and names at once

Tags: r

Is there a convenient way to combine these 2 steps into one?

```
df = data.frame(aa = 'A', ab = '', n = 'C')
#  aa  ab  n
#   A      C

temp = df[ grep('a', names(df)) ]          
#  aa  ab  
#   A       

ans = temp[ temp != '' ]
# [1] "A"
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way assuming your dataframe has only one row -

```
df[grepl("a", names(df)) & df != '']

[1] "A"
```

Thanks to @thelatemail, here's a generalized solution for any number of rows -

```
df <- data.frame(aa = c('A','B'), ab = c('','T'), n = c('C', 'C'))

df[grepl("a", names(df)[col(df)]) & df != '']

[1] "A" "B" "T"
```

Comment: I think you have to get trickier for multiple rows though, maybe - `df[grepl("a", names(df)[col(df)]) & df != '']` ?

Comment: @thelatemail That's beautiful! I did attempt a generalized solution but didn't see this. Thanks!

Comment: great solutions.  Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

## tidyverse  way

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(aa = 'A', ab = '', n = 'C')
df.long <-gather(df, col) #chaging to long format and key is col
df.long %>%
filter(col %in% grep("a",col, value = T) & value != '')
```